# Using Extendscript to Import a Visio Object By Reference into FrameMaker

Tags: javascript, extendscript, framemaker

My colleagues and I import our Visio files into FrameMaker via the following mechanism:
File > Import > Object... > Create from File (with Link checked).

I want to accomplish the same action using ExtendScript, where the file being imported is selected automatically (via the script). I've tried numerous import-script settings using the Import() method, but I get a FV_BadImportScriptValue error.  I think it is because the hint string for object linking and embedding is not published anywhere (that I can find).

Ultimately, what I'm really trying to accomplish is to rename a Visio file that has already been linked and embedded, and then reimport the renamed file.  I can rename files by first extracting the old file name from the OLE2 facet and renaming the old file on disk with its new name.  I can't reimport the renamed file, however. When I do, I get the BadImportScriptValue error.  In lieu of reimporting the renamed file, tweaking the existing OLE2 facet to link to the newly renamed file would be option, if I only knew how to do that.  Reimporting seemed like the cleanest approach--I just can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul